# Cumulative product in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have data in the following format:

```
1.09
1.05
0.94
0.77
1.09
1.21
0.83
```

How do I output the cumulative product in JavaScript? In Excel this would be like: `=PRODUCT(A$1:A1)` and the results would be:

```
1.09    1.09
1.05    1.14
0.94    1.08
0.77    0.83
1.09    0.90
1.21    1.09
0.83    0.91
```

Comment: It would be "with code".

Comment: using a loop and a variable to hold the accumulated value - I'd recommend Array#reduce if your data is an Array - except the "format" of the data in your question isn't anything useful to javascript - so the first thing you need to do is to get that data into some sort of format that is "compatible" with javascript coding practices

Comment: It looks as though you have a history of [not doing enough research before asking questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418). If you continue with this pattern of asking instead of searching you will likely end up question banned. Please invest more of your time into finding answers for yourself on your own, and only ask a question when you get stuck on a *specific, answerable* issue.

Comment: @zzzzBov What is "question banned"?

Comment: @guest271314 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/153542

Comment: @zzzzBov Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply run a forEach loop that would update an outside variable like this code example

```
var in = dataset; //Define the initial dataset
var out = 1; //Define the output (Using 1 because 1 is the multiplicative identity)
in.forEach(function(element){ //Looping over every element in 'in'
    out *= element; //Setting out = out*element
}
console.log(out); //Outputting the final output
```

This should be the simplest way to achieve your goals.

Comment: `reduce` would be a better approach, but please don't feed the vampires.

Comment: @zzzzBov what do you mean by 'feed the vampires'?

Comment: [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: @zzzzBov Ahhh, I see now. Thanks for the link! I love the sardonic humor.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everybody who gave (constructive) answers. Here is my solution:

```
input = [1.09,1.05,0.94,0.77,1.09,1.21,0.83]
output = []
x = 1
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
x = x * input[i]
output.push(x)
}
```